# spreadsheet API multiply two columns and write the results as another column with python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to multiply C and E columns and write the results to the G column but I couldn't figure it out. Do you have any idea how I can do that?

```
request_body ={
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": spreadsheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 2,
          "endRowIndex": 15,
          "startColumnIndex": 7,
          "endColumnIndex": 8
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredValue": {
              "formulaValue": "=FLOOR(E2*C2)"
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredValue"
      }
    }
  ]
}


response = serviceSheets.spreadsheets().values().update(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
body=request_body
).execute()
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current script?

Comment: I get this error and couldn't solve

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests" at 'data': Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'data', 'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests" at \'data\': Cannot find field.'}]}]">

Comment: when I change the method to batchUpdate I get this error:

'requests[0].repeat_cell.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "1Iknox10drdCsOXETvLyyahPFjs2s24UIci40ilbpzZA"". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0].repeat_cell.range.sheet_id', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'requests[0].repeat_cell.range.sheet_id\' (TYPE_INT32), "1Iknox10drdCsOXETvLyyahPFjs2s24UIci40ilbpzZA"'}]}]">

Comment: Spreadsheet and sheet are different things. Sheet means a tab. The id would be present in the url  after `#gridid=`. Also [edit]  your question with the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are using [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate?hl=en) which doesn't contain a `repeatCell` request in its [Request body](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate?hl=en#request-body)

You need to use [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate?hl=en) if you want to use a [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request?hl=en#repeatcellrequest)

In addition, as mentioned by @TheMaster, you are using an incorrect id as your `sheetId`, it should be the `gid` found in the URL when you view your target sheet tab.Please also keep in mind that [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#gridrange) starts at `zero-index`. And the end index is excluded.

### Sample Code:

```
request_body ={
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": spreadsheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 15,
          "startColumnIndex": 7,
          "endColumnIndex": 8
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredValue": {
              "formulaValue": "=FLOOR(E2*C2)"
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredValue"
      }
    }
  ]
}


response = serviceSheets.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
body=request_body
).execute()
```

### Output:

[image]

- Since I used endRowIndex = 15, Cell H16 formula was not set.

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues during your implementation. I only used the API explorer to test the sample request body.

Comment: Omg you and The Master literally saved my life! Thank you very much. The problem was spreed_id. I authorized the app with credentials.json file so I was thinking spreadsheetId is enough. When I change the sheetId it worked! Thank you guys . All the best!